# Why isn't the validation data loss close to the test data loss?

Tags: neural-network, keras, validation, learning

First I set aside about 15% of my data as test data. Then, I used tensorflow.keras to create a relatively simple neural net model. Then I set the model.fit() parameter validation_split=0.2, so 20% of the remaining 85% (roughly 68% of the original 70,000 instances) was set aside as validation data (not for training). My optimizer was 'adam' and my metric was 'accuracy'.

I plotted the learning curves (loss vs epoch history.history['val_accuracy'] and accuracy vs epoch, history.history['accuracy']), and I also got the loss & accuracy for the test data (model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0) )

Here's my question: why does the validation loss & accuracy closely track the training loss & accuracy EVEN THOUGH the test loss is much, much higher and the test accuracy is much much lower? I expected the test loss & accuracy to be about the same order of magnitude as the validation ones for the last epoch.

I have tried randomly altering the order of instances (and their labels) before each run, I've tried changing the epoch size, I've tried changing the batch size, I've tried changing the validation split (say, to 50%), I've tried changing the loss function, I've changed the number of layers (wildly), and also the number of nodes per hidden layer (also wildly). No matter what I do, the result is the same: the validation loss and accuracy very closely track the training loss and accuracy, and the testing are way, way worse.

Shouldn't the validation loss and accuracy in the last epoch be roughly around the those for the testing data?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi @Alex, welcome to the site. What kind of data do you have? How did you split the data in training, validation and test sets? These 2 factors can very much justify a poor performance on the test data, as they can lead to different distributions of the validation and test sets, e.g. split by year in time series, split by speaker in speech data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.